# How to input Subtitle from a file

Tags: titles, input, thesis

I am using this [template](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template) to write a thesis. While using the `\subtitle` command I am having a problem. If I follow the syntax like

```
\subtitle{This is the subtitle}
```

it works. However, if I wish to input the subtitle text from a `subtitle.tex` file like

```
\subtitle{\input{subtitle}}
```

it gives me an error.

Interestingly, other commands such as `\title, \submissiontext, \degree` are working fine accepting the input from `.tex` files.

I wish to follow the same approach with the `\subtitle` command as well.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `\subtitle` isn't a standard command and you have not shown its definition and you say it gives an error but you have not shown the error message. That makes it hard to offer any real help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You can get the definition in the `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` file following the link given above. The error message is 'Argument of \@iinput has an extra }.'

Comment: external links are discouraged here but the class does `\ifthenelse{\equal{\@subtitle}{}}{` which is an "optomistic" test for being empty. As you know it is not empty  you could change it to `\ifthenelse{\equal{zz}{}}{` so it always takes the non empty branch

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your prompt response. But it's not working. It gives the same error message.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I accept your argument how can the command - `\subtitle{This is the subtitle}` works fine?

Comment: because text is safe in ifthenelse and \ input is not (you could remove the entire test from the class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify/expand David Carlisle comments.

(1) Open `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` with a text editor.

(2) Change lines #1148 to #1160  which are now

```
% Title Box
\newsavebox{\PHD@Title}
\begin{lrbox}{\PHD@Title}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}
    \centering \Huge \bfseries{\@title}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@subtitle}{}}{
      % subtitle is not defined
    }{
      \\
      \centering \Large {\@subtitle}
    } % subtitle is defined
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
```

for

```
% Title Box
\newsavebox{\PHD@Title}
\begin{lrbox}{\PHD@Title}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}
    \centering \Huge \bfseries{\@title}
      \\
      \centering \Large {\@subtitle} % subtitle is defined
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
```

(3) Save the file.

(4) Use `\subtitle{\input{subtitle}}` and you will get

[image: a]